# R coding for max(trt1)/max(trt2)

Tags: r

I am asked to code in R for permutation test of max(trt1)/max(trt2) and find p_value left, right, and both sided,I tried but couldn't make it, 
here is my coding:

```
trt1 <- c(45, 67, 27, 55)
trt2 <- c(34, 54, 37, 40)

permTestMax<- function(trt1=trt1, trt2=trt2) {
    n1<- length(trt1)
    n2<- length(trt2) 
    TS_obs<- max(trt1)/max(trt2)
    TS_obs
    perm = combn(c(trt1,trt2),n1)
    nperm = ncol(perm)
    TS<- array(0,dim=c(nperm))
    for(i in 1: nperm) {
        TS[i]<-max(perm[,i])
    } 

    TS[TS >= TS_obs]
    P_upper<- max(TS >= TS_obs)
    P_lower<- max(TS <= TS_obs)P_two_tail<- max(abs(TS)>= abs(TS_obs))
    P_equalTo<- max(abs(TS)== abs(TS_obs))
    print("Exact Permulation Test for Comparing Maximum of the response")
    print(cbind(n1,max(trt1), n2, max(trt2)))
    print(cbind(TS_obs, nperm, P_upper, P_lower, P_two_tail, P_equalTo))
}

permTestMax(trt1=trt1, trt2=trt2)
```

I am not getting a right answer, Can anybody help please?

Comment: This is not a good place to get help on your homework. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to see how you can ask a good question ...

Comment: Hi Aditya, I am asking for coding max(trt1)/max(trt2) function on R, I am doing everything right as far as I understand, still getting wrong p-values.

Comment: On my PC I get a result and no error. I do not know about the statistical you mention but this seems to be programming related and not statistics related anyway. What output do you expect and what do you get instead? You can [edit] your question to add these details. (Also, the code in your question is not formatted correctly, you can fix that while you're at it)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am getting p_upper=0, p_lower=1, and p_two-tail=0.5, It seems incorrect to me, are u getting the same answer?

Comment: I believe its wrong